# Flutter - AWS Amplify Storage from existing bucket

Tags: flutter, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I new with S3 storage for flutter, and have the following (basic) question, which I cannot get to the bottom of.

I understand with Amplify for Flutter, the app can upload and read stuff from the S3 storage bucket. I have succeeded in doing this.

However, my question is, if I have items already stored on the S3 server, and I want my app to be able to read and list the items there, how can I do it. Meaning, I don't want to upload from the app to there, rather it is an existing bucket with data, that I want the app to be able to read. Also, I don't want there to have to be a login, and all the examples I see for using S3 with flutter is when there is authenticaion login.

Sorry for the basic question, but I'm getting confused from the start. Any basic guidance will be of great help. Or links to tutorial, etc

Thanks

Comment: Hey, Have you found any solution yet?. Becouse, I'm to struggling in this.

Comment: No, I didn't get anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/existing-resources/q/platform/ios/

I know it's the ios docs, but it appears to work for Flutter.

Run `amplify import storage` follow the prompts to select your bucket.

Run `amplify push`.

Your storage should now use your pre-existing s3 bucket. Look in the Amplify console to confirm.

Comment: found the same command on the amplify cli page: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/storage/import/

Comment: for flutter: https://docs.amplify.aws/flutter/build-a-backend/storage/existing-resources/